# Rename Variables in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I rename variables in SWI Prolog?

I tried to use numbervars predicate like this.

```
numbervars(Xs,1,_,[functor_name(name)]).
```

So if Xs is a list of 4 variables, it will look like this when I commit 'writeln(Xs)'.

```
[name(1),name(2),name(3),name(4)]
```

How can I use that functor, or any other way to remove the parenthesis and make it looks like:

```
[name1,name2,name3,name4]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own subset of `numbervars/4` (or completely rewrite your own, if you wish). Here's a subset that performs the specific task you're describing:

```
build_atoms([Var|VarList], N, Prefix) :-
    atom_number(Atom, N),
    atom_concat(Prefix, Atom, Var),
    N1 is N + 1,
    build_atoms(VarList, N1, Prefix).
build_atoms([], _, _).
```

This accepts a list of variables and instantiates them in sequence with the atom given in `Prefix` contactenated with integers, starting with `N`.

For example:

```
?- X = [A,B,C], build_atoms(X, 1, foo).
X = [foo1, foo2, foo3],
A = foo1,
B = foo2,
C = foo3.

?-
```

This can easily be expanded to include any other functionality in `numbervars` that you desire.

Comment: one more thing please.
looks like I can't asign values to that variables after I used build_atoms. Well, it makes sense after all.
Is there any way to make it [Foo1,Foo2,Foo3] instead of [foo1,foo2,foo3].
Such that when I run ?-foo(X),X=[0,1,1].

where foo(X):-length(X,3),build_atoms(X,1,<VarName>). 
it will work?

I mean, that names replace the real values which will be asigned later in my program. I want it only to be the variable names when I print it to terminal.

I hope I was clear, thanks again.

Comment: @Mockingbird I see. If you want the effect of dynamic variable names, perhaps a more canonical approach would be to use key/value pairs instead. So you would use `build_atoms` to create key names, and then assign values to them in a list that looks like, `[foo1-val1, foo2-val2, ...]`.

Comment: @Mockingbird I just thought of another way, which might be more suitable but it depends upon your application. A simple predicate could be written such that `X = [A,B,C], build_vars(X, 1, foo).` would generate `X = [foo(1,_), foo(2,_), foo(3,_)]`. Then you can fill in the value for `foo(n, Value)` as needed, and then you could do something like, `member(foo(n, Value), X)` to get a `Value` for a given `n`.